# Testing an observable on a service property using jasmine.SpyObj - Angular/Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm trying to test an observable that is bound to an inline property rather than a method on a service, however I can't seem to find any examples about how to return the correct value either in the SpyObj itself or through a spyOn/SpyOnProperty call.

```
// ContentService 
readonly content$ = this.http.get('www.testContent.com');

// ParentService
constructor(private readonly contentService: ContentService){
  this.loadContent();
}

// This could return different content dependent on locale for example
loadContent(){
  this.contentService.content$.subscribe((response)=>{
    // Handle response
  })
}

// Unit test 
let service: ParentService;
let contentServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ContentService>;

beforeEach(() => {
  const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ContentService', [], {
    // Returns cannot read subscribe of undefined
    content$: of()
  });

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      ParentService,
      { provide: ContentService, useValue: spy }
    ]
  });

  service = TestBed.get(ParentService);
  contentServiceSpy = TestBed.get(ContentService) as jasmine.SpyObj<ContentService>;
});
```

I've seen a couple of examples about using spyOnProperty with get and set methods but that's not what's happening here, am I declaring it incorrectly on the jasmine.SpyObj or is there a particular jasmine method that I'm missing to return the desired value from the `content$`

Comment: Shouldn't there be `{ provide: ContentService, useValue: { content$: spy() } }` instead of `ValueService` ? As far as I can see, the parent injects `ContentService`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do in these scenarios is I add an instance property to the `createSpyObj` itself.

```
// Unit test 
let service: ParentService;
let contentServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ContentService>;
let mockContent$ = new BehaviorSubject(/* content mock goes here*/);

beforeEach(() => {
  const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ContentService', ['loadContent']);

  spy.content$ = mockContent$; // add the instance property itself

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      ParentService,
      { provide: ValueService, useValue: spy }
    ]
  });

  service = TestBed.get(ParentService);
  contentServiceSpy = TestBed.get(ContentService) as jasmine.SpyObj<ContentService>;
});
```

Later on, if you want to change the value of `content$`, you can do `mockContent$.next(/* new mock content goes here*/);`

Comment: Legend that worked like a charm, I'm going to assume there isn't a way to achieve this with the spyObj & spyOn.return directly then?

Comment: That's the way I do it. I remember doing some brief research and I resorted in that being the best option. If you want to play around and maybe even come up with a better way that suits you, feel free.

Comment: No no I'm quite happy with this approach was just curious, have given you the answer :)